# Laravel - How to take contents of one table and set as object of the results of join

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables named user and comments.

```
User                 Comments
id| name             id| description| user_id
---------            ------------------------
1 Sam                1 Awesome dude  1
2 Dean               2 Cool          1
                     3 Ghost busters 2
```

how can i join tables to get result like the following.

```
{
 id:1,
 name: Sam
 comments:[
   {
     id:1,
     description:Awesome dude
   },
   {
     id:2,
     description:Cool
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Take a look at Laravel's Orm.  And remove this question before you get a bunch of down votes.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Comment: @TarekAdam I checked it, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: where is your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try laravel `ORM`

Write this relationship inside your `User` model

```
protected $with = [ 'comments'];

function comments ()
{ 
    return $this->hasMany(Comments::class,  'user_id', 'id');
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. with this reference i was able to solve my issue. I had to add 
User::with('comments')->join()...->get()